# How to develop for iOS gesture events in a web app in Windows Desktop?

Tags: javascript, ios, windows, multi-touch

I am developing a web app that should respond to gesture events in iPad (pinch in and out should perform some custom zoom in and out in my web app). I don't have a Mac, so is there a simulator in Windows that will generate these events somehow, so I can develop against it?

Comment: The users are going to be using a browser to get to your website right?  Shouldn't pinch zooming be something the browser is supposed to handle on it's own?  I don't think you have to build any customized support for it in your web app, if my understanding is correct.  But I may be wrong.

Comment: do you have an iPad to test with? and, as you say 'some custom zoom' does that imply not just the standard browser behavior?

Comment: @GeneralMike, In my page i have some div to zoom, not a whole page!

Comment: @Robot Woods, i don't have an iPad.I not going to do anything in the page. i have some divs in my page, when someone pinch in/out i have to change the width of the divs.

Comment: @BalaKrishnan: ahh, I gotcha.  My next guess would be trying to find a way to make it so the browser will treat each division as a separate window (if that's possible), and see if the browser will make it behave the way you want it to from there.  I'm actually not too familiar with building webapps (the ios tag is what caught my eye), so that's about as much as I can offer.